# what are the advatanges and disavantages of the digital signature algorithms for JWT?

Tags: signature, jwt

I am using a Java JWT library [jose4j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home).
There is a list of digital signatures algorithms which can be used.

- HMAC using SHA-2
- RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5 Digital Signatures with with SHA-2
- Elliptic Curve Digital Signatures (ECDSA) with SHA-2
- RSASSA-PSS Digital Signatures with SHA-2

I tried to understand what the advantages/disadvantages of the algorithms are but Google searches of "HMAC vs RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5" did not return results.

What are the pros/cons of these algorithms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answer is not original, as I am simply summing up information from different questions already solved in this site. Nevertheless, I thought it could be interesting to collect everything in one answer.

The first thing you have to know is to differentiate between a digital signature and a message authentication code (MAC). In this case, HMAC is a MAC and the rest (RSA and ECDSA) are digital signatures.

[This answer to a previous question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5646/what-are-the-differences-between-a-digital-signature-a-mac-and-a-hash) gives you an excellent overview of the different characteristics of both categories. As you can see, the main difference between HMAC and conventional digital signatures are:

- HMAC uses symmetric keys (so both parties have to share a common secret), while Digital Signatures use asymmetric keys (i.e., public key crypto, so the prover uses a secret key, and the verifier uses an associated public key). This also has implications regarding performance, since symmetric crypto is usually much faster.
- Digital Signatures provide non-repudiation of origin, while HMAC don't.

That is the first differential factor between them. Now, we could focus on the difference among digital signatures schemes:

- RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5 Digital Signatures with with SHA-2
- Elliptic Curve Digital Signatures (ECDSA) with SHA-2
- RSASSA-PSS Digital Signatures with SHA-2

In this case, the main differences are not about functionality, but about the underlying mathematical primitives, namely RSA vs Elliptic Curves. This also has been [covered before](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3216/signatures-rsa-compared-to-ecdsa/3218#3218). To sum up, the implications are mainly centered on performance, size of keys, implementations, etc.

Finally, this [other answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3850/is-rsassa-pkcs1-v1-5-a-good-signature-scheme-for-new-systems) covers the difference between RSASSA-PSS and RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5. To sum up, the difference is mainly of theoretical interest, concerning the proof of security.